# Removing listeners before dispose flutter

Tags: flutter

If i initialise a watcher in the initState() e.g.

```
textController.addListener(textTypedListener);
```

Do i need to manually remove the listener before I dispose of the text controller? or does the dispose automatically handle this.

eg. Options 1

```
 @override
  void dispose() {
    textController.removeListener(textTypedListener);
    textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Option 2

```
 @override
  void dispose() {
    textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Which is best?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

According to the [Interactive Example](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes) given in the flutter documentation of **Handle changes to a text field**, it's commented that ***calling dispose also removes the listener***.

So the second option would be best.

Comment: Ok thank you. Is this the case for all controllers? not just the TextEditingWidget.

Comment: @ebg11 yes it is