# ChangeNotifier listeners and dispose. Memory leaks?

Tags: flutter, memory-leaks, listener, dispose, flutter-change-notifier

I am curious if creation of new objects removes all attached listeners.
Here it is simple code:

```dart
class Notifier extends ChangeNotifier {}

final notifier = Notifier();

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  // Should I remove listeners before creation new instance of `Notifier`?
  // Or new instantiaion assumes that all listeners attached to object will be removed?
  notifier?.removeListener(_listener);
  notifier = Notifier();
  notifier.addListener(_listener);
}

void _listener() {}
```

Comment: This was answered at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61759948/removing-listerers-before-dispose-flutter